# how to stop dragging of adf column based on its height

Tags: java, oracle-adf

While dragging on an adf column to left side it is increasing its height towards down, but at particular height I want to disable dragging (Based on height reference iam enabling and disabling column dragging). Please any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you maybe provide a visualization of what you mean because it is kind of hard to understand?

Comment: Thanks alistra for your promt response..it has been resolved already